# apache2 redirect going to default domain

Tags: apache2, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all requests for ardsley73.com (or at least [www.ardsley73.com](http://www.ardsley73.com)) to [www.ardsleyhigh73.com](http://www.ardsleyhigh73.com). I tried the following rewrite rule in sites-available/ardsley73.conf, but after enabling it and restarting apache it's not working. A redirect takes place, but it's to what appears to be the default (or first) site configured on my server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ardsley73.com
    ServerAlias www.ardsley73.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^www\.ardsley73\.com" [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^$"
    RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"        "https://www.ardsleyhigh73.com/$1" [L,R,NE]
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong? Beyond not knowing apache configuration all that well... :)

**Additional Info**

Here is 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin mark@arcabama.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is 286chestnut.conf, the site that is being erroneously displayed:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName olbert.com
    ServerAlias 286chestnut.olbert.com

    Redirect permanent / https://286chestnut.olbert.com/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =286chestnut.olbert.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =olbert.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and here is 286chestnut-le-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin mark@arcabama.com
    ServerName olbert.com
    ServerAlias 286chestnut.olbert.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/olbert.com/286chestnut/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/olbert.com/286chestnut/public_html>
        Require all granted
        # Allow local .htaccess to override Apache configuration settings
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

    # Enable RewriteEngine
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteOptions inherit

    # Specify which version of PHP to run since we have several
    # (added 6/17/2022 per https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-multiple-php-versions-on-one-server-using-apache-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-18-04)
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
      # For Apache version 2.4.10 and above, use SetHandler to run PHP as a fastCGI process server
      SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>


    # Block .svn, .git
    RewriteRule \.(svn|git)(/)?$ - [F]

    # Recommended: XSS protection
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
        Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    </IfModule>

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/286chestnut.olbert.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/286chestnut.olbert.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

My (limited) understanding is that 286chestnut.conf redirects to https://, whose configuration is governed by 286chestnut-le-ssl.conf.

Comment: "in sites-available/ardsley73.conf, but after enabling it" - How did you _enable it_? Ultimately, the config needs to be found in `site-enabled` (usually via a symlink back to `sites-available`). Otherwise, you need to find out why the default/first vHost appears to be catching the request. Please post the default vHost (which includes the redirect you are seeing). The redirect code you posted is also incorrect, but that is secondary to your main problem as this code doesn't seem to be being processed at all currently.

Comment: Domains are matched by Apache based on the alphabetical name of the config file. If your first site is being loaded, then the configuration file for that site may have some aliases in place that capture the domain. Generally I have the "default" site use a file name like `999-whatever.conf` and all other sites are given numbers like `100-first.conf`, `101-second.conf`, and so on 

Comment: I'm continuing to play around with this problem. I read about how you can use wget to see redirects (I tried logging them but couldn't get that to work). Interestingly, doing a wget on www.ardsley73.com does, in fact, retrieve the correct index.html file that WordPress generates. But entering www.ardsley73.com in the browser address bar does not (even in a private window so I don't have to worry about caching problems)

Comment: It looks like the complaint is the ardsley73.com server can't prove it's secure because it's using the 286chestnut.olbert.com certificate (which doesn't cover ardsley73.com, or ardsleyhigh73.com, for that matter -- it has its own certificate). Apparently authenticating identity takes place >>before<< the redirect to www.ardsleyhigh73.com, which is not what I would've expected. Could I solve the problem by expanding the ardsleyhigh73.com certificate to include all the other remapped sites? If so, do I just put the certificate reference in each remapped site's config file (e.g., ardsley73.conf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of those who run into similar problems...

Apparently, authenticating identity (at least from within Edge and Chrome) takes place before any redirect to a different website occurs. Consequently, if the "initial" site is not secured by a certificate, the redirect will not occur until after the user agrees to move forward.

That's not what I would've expected. But the solution is fairly straightforward: secure the "initial" sites. This is easy enough to do with Let's Encrypt and certbot, which is what I use.

Comment: Having this issue on our prod server, this answers all the mysteries.